# Change the page color of a word document using python

Tags: python, colors, python-docx

I created a word document using python and docx module. I want some method to change the background color of the whole document, but I can't find any. Any ideas?

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654472/modify-the-xml-in-paragraph-style-element-xml-in-python-docx).

- First create two Word files. One with the formatting you like, one completely empty. Save them.
- Extract the docx files using some unzip tool.
- Open the files `settings.xml` and `document.xml` and compare the files from the two docx files using a diff tool, e.g. Winmerge or Meld
- Look for `<w:background w:color="004586"/>` in `document.xml`
- Look for `<w:displayBackgroundShape/>` in `settings.xml`

Now try to set the fields using the method mentioned above.

If that does not work you can follow the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61628660/7919597) for LibreOffice files (open as XML, modify or add nodes, save, zip).

Answer (score 0):

Detailed explanation of the approach by [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7919597/joe)  and [Post Referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654472/modify-the-xml-in-paragraph-style-element-xml-in-python-docx) using [python-docx](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/).

```
import docx
from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_paragraph().add_run("Sample Text")

# Now Add below children to root xml tree
# create xml element using OxmlElement
shd = OxmlElement('w:background')
# Add attributes to the xml element
shd.set(qn('w:color'), '0D0D0D') #black color
shd.set(qn('w:themeColor'), 'text1')
shd.set(qn('w:themeTint'), 'F2')

# Add background element at the start of Document.xml using below
doc.element.insert(0,shd)

# Add displayBackgroundShape element to setting.xml
shd1 = OxmlElement('w:displayBackgroundShape')
doc.settings.element.insert(0,shd1)

# Save to file
doc.save('sample.docx')
```